# How to convert number to special format

Tags: javascript

I have a number which is : `410226497.3017611`

I want to convert it to : `410.226`

Here's my current code.

```
(data/1000000).toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 1, maximumFractionDigits: 1})
```

However the above doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you explain what the format of the input is? Do you need the 6 first digits of the input ? Do you need to integer part divided by a hundred?

Comment: You should make sure that data is a number, as your LocaleString conversion works: `Number(199999342).toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 1, maximumFractionDigits: 1})` gives `199,999,342.0`

Comment: your result have fractional digit length 3. ''' (data/1000000).toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 3, maximumFractionDigits: 3}) '''

Comment: yes i need the 6 first digits of the input. the input is number

Comment: Can you explan what "doesn't work" means? Is there an error/exception? Wrong result? Which?

Answer (score 1):

If you execute your code, you see:

Input:

```
var data = 410226497.3017611;
(data/1000000).toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 1, maximumFractionDigits: 1})
```

Output:

```
"410.2"
```

At documentation for [toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) there is description about `minimumFractionDigits` and `maximumFractionDigits`.

You can change `maximumFractionDigits` to `3`. Then:

Input:

```
(410226497.3017611/1000000).toLocaleString('en-US', {minimumFractionDigits: 1, maximumFractionDigits: 3})
```

Output:

```
"410.226"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Number.prototype.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) like so:

```
(data / 1000000).toFixed(3);
```

What this does is it limits the number of digits allowed after the decimal point of a floating-point value - so if we did this:

```
Math.PI.toFixed(4)
```

It would just take the float being passed (3.141592...), and slice of everything after the fourth digit after the decimal, therefore returning 3.1415.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you always want 3 decimal digits, you can try using

```
var a = 410226497.3017611;
(a/1000000).toFixed(3);  # this will return "410.226"
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to retrieve the first 6 digits of the number:

```
const a = 410226497.3017611;
const firstSix = (a+'').slice(0,6) // "410226"
```

Then, you parse it back into a number and divide by 1000:

```
const final = Number(firstSix)/1000

console.log(final) // 410.226
```